# Ebean One-to-many relationship in same entity

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm trying to create a `@OneToMany` relationship in the same entity. Here is a sample code:

```
@Entity
public class Client extends Model{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Client(String username, String email) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Id
    String username;

    @Required
    String email;

    @ManyToOne
    Client parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    Set<Client> friends = new HashSet<Client>();

    static Finder<String,Client> find = new Finder<String,Client>(String.class, Client.class);

    public static void create(Client regUser){
        regUser.save();
    }

    public static Client getByUsername(String username){
        return find.byId(username);
    }

    public void addFriend(Client relatedClient){
        this.friends.add(relatedClient);
        relatedClient.update();
        this.update();
    }

    /**
     * @return the username
     */
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    /**
     * @param username the username to set
     */
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    /**
     * @return the email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * @param email the email to set
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     * @return the friends
     */
    public Set<Client> getFriends() {
        return friends;
    }

    /**
     * @param friends the friends to set
     */
    public void setFriends(Set<Client> friends) {
        this.friends = friends;
    }

    /**
     * @return the parent
     */
    public Client getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    /**
     * @param parent the parent to set
     */
    public void setParent(Client parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }


    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Client [username=" + username + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }
}
```

The problem is that after adding a new friend to a `Client` and searching for the same `Client` by Id, the friend list isn't updated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your entity in an existing project I have setup, and it seems to work fine for me. I'm using play 2.1.1 with java 1.7, and Scala 2.10.0. There is [this issue with enhancement](http://www.poornerd.com/2013/01/04/play-framework-2-0-ebean-lazy-loading-and-object-references-that-are-null/) that could be causing your issue.

Comment: additional note: i was getting a null email field for Clients in the parent's friends list, but adding the query: 'Ebean.find(Client.class).fetch("friends").where().eq("username", username).findUnique();' and calling that does not return nulls for the email address field.